# Save button is disabled in Flow builder

Tags: visual-workflow

Save button is disabled in Flow builder. Even after i save this as a New Version, the Save Button is not enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you had activated the flow previously. Once you activate a flow you cannot edit the same version even if you deactivate it. You need to use `Save As` and create either a new version of the flow or a new flow

Comment: I tried doing "Save As". and in-spite of that the Save Button is disabled.

Comment: Did you perform any changes to the flow after creating a new version? If you change something in the flow save button will be enabled

Comment: Thank you. It worked!! 

Much Appreciated.